# TFS 2015 - Plugin vs Web Hooks

Tags: tfs, webhooks, tfs-2015

I have a TFS plugin as a part of my application that sends out alerts to a web API URL when anything changes on that TFS 2015 instance. The Web API processes those alerts as required.

Now I recently came to know about the 
[Web Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/webhooks-and-vso-vs) feature in TFS 2015 which essentially accomplishes something similar.

I'm considering getting rid of the TFS Plugin and switching onto the Web Hooks simply because I will need to maintain one less component. However, reliability is most important to me. So, is there a way to find out if the latter is more reliable than the former, or if it's the other way around?

Also, does TFS give preference to either in terms of execution order? I've been told that the web hooks capture the field values (for a WorkItem) when the event is created. Whereas the plugin retrieves the fields after the event is fired so there might be a small lag time.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that web hooks aren't reliable? Conversely, do you have any reason to suspect that your plugin isn't reliable? How do you measure "reliability" in this case, anyway? Does the web hook send a message when the event occurs? It's reliable. Does your plugin send a message when the event occurs? It's equally reliable.

Comment: I don't know if the web hooks are reliable or otherwise and hence the reason for posting this question.

Comment: I can understand that if a web hook sends a message when the event occurs or if the plugin sends a message when the event occurs then they should be considered reliable. That goes without saying but these are happy path scenarios and I'm talking about failure scenarios. The plugin has a chance of crashing but that might not be the case with web hooks. But then, are there any caveats with web hooks?